# Everything in Git shows as "new file"

Tags: git

I had just committed and pushed some code from a feature branch to my pull request, and then about a minute later my computer unexpectedly rebooted. When I logged back in and opened Intellij every file in my root folder tree had turned green, and executing "git status" shows that basically every file in my repository (hundreds of files) is marked as "new file" and displayed under the "changes to be committed" section.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you run `git status` from the command line, what do you get?

Comment: @mason _” executing "git status" shows that basically every file in my repository (hundreds of files) is marked as "new file" and displayed under the "changes to be committed" section.”_

Comment: You could always try the [tried and true method](https://xkcd.com/1597/) of fixing Git issues.

Comment: Do you see all of those files via www (where you are doing this PR)?

Comment: It's true, the simplest approach is to throw this folder away and clone fresh. That is one reason you have a remote repo: it's backup.

Comment: @Boken My pull request in Stash looks fine. I look at the last commit I made, and it only includes the 8 files that I actually made changes to and wanted to push. Nothing in my pull request looks odd.

Comment: Or clone fresh to a new folder and do a comparison in case the old repo has untracked files that you need.

Comment: If I had to delete the folder and clone a new one, how would I do that? I know the Git command that I used before to clone it (git clone ssh://git@stash...etc, etc), but what about getting rid of the old folder? Am I able to use the same location as before, or do I have to clone to a new folder location, and then set up intellij pointing to the new location?

Comment: You can rename the current folder (rather than deleting, just as an extra level of precaution so you can run diffs on it) then create a new folder with the same name and clone into that.

Comment: How many files are in this project? Do you recognize any of the file names from the `git status` output?

Answer (score 0):

Note: it's possible that IntelliJ (which does its own things) may be making this worse than it is when it's just an issue where the crash-and-reboot corrupted a file or two.  The rest of this answer is specific to the Git-only case.

> I had just committed and pushed some code from a feature branch to my pull request, and then about a minute later my computer unexpectedly rebooted.

When your computer crashes and reboots—and subsequently repairs or removes files that were never properly saved just before this step—this may affect a Git repository.  Since Git itself mostly works by *adding new things* to an existing repository, it's often recoverable, except perhaps for the most-recently-added things.  But you should:

1. Run `git fsck`, to verify that only "normal" items are affected.  This may print lots of messages about dangling and/or unreachable commits and/or blobs.  These really *are* normal.  If you get any fatal errors, the repository itself may be very damaged.
2. If `git fsck` claims that the repository is not even a *repository*, the `HEAD` file may be missing.  This file contains the *name of the current branch* and it can be quite active (because it changes every time you change branches).  If Git rewrote it recently, your OS may have deleted the file due to the crash.  If so, you can *create a new `HEAD` file* that refers to whichever branch you were on.  Just create the file with content:

   ```
   ref: refs/heads/master
   ```

   for instance, if you were on `master`.  Then return to step 1.
3. If `git fsck` believes the repository is OK, use `git status` to check the status.

   - If this shows that *every file is a new file*, see which branch Git thinks you are on (due to the `HEAD` file described in step 2, but `git status` tell you which branch you are on).  Your OS has deleted the *branch* file.  This file should contain the hash ID of the *current commit*.  The correct current commit hash ID is probably being shown as a *dangling commit* in the `git fsck` output.

     Your job is to find (somehow) the correct hash ID and create your branch name again using that hash ID.  This can be difficult, especially since the crash-and-reboot probably lost you any view in which you could *see* the hash ID.  You can test out each of the `dangling commit` hash IDs that `git fsck` prints, but since these *are* normal, and only *one* of them can be correct, this can be one of those needle-in-a-haystack cases.<sup>1</sup>

     If the correct hash ID is, say, `7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570` (it won't be—this was the one in the test repository I used while constructing the answer, and I had carefully saved it away myself) and the branch name is `master`, you could re-create the `master` branch with:

     ```
     git update-ref refs/heads/master 7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570
     ```

     or:

     ```
     echo 7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570 > .git/refs/heads/master
     ```
   - If on the other hand every *existing* file shows as *untracked*, this means your OS has deleted Git's *index* file.  It is easy to rebuild the index file from the current commit: simply run `git reset`.  Note that any carefully staged changes (e.g., via `git add -p`) will be lost.  The correct object for such things is in one of the `dangling blob` hash IDs that `git fsck` printed, if you wish to go searching for it.

   If your OS has deleted both the branch file *and* Git's index, you need to take both recovery actions (create the branch entry first, then Git's index).

   If you have an old, stale *packed reference* entry for the current branch, then when your OS deletes the branch *file*, your current branch will roll back to some older commit.  In this case you can once again look for dangling commits, as in the first bullet point under step 3.

This usually covers everything except *missing or damaged object files and/or missing or damaged files in your working tree*.  These are not easily recovered, except for damaged blob objects that are Git-ified copies of correct plain-text files in your working tree: here you can just remove the damaged blob object and run `git add` on the working tree file.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually rather worse, since a magnet usually works well for extracting an actual needle from a pile of nonmagnetic material.  It's a bit more of a "needle in a pile of needles" case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you added the files to your repository but for some reason failed to do the initial commit:

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

This happened to me when I got pulled away from one project to work on an urgent project, then returned to my project several months later.  Running the above command fixed everything.  The absence of the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` is your biggest clue that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but this might help someone.

I had a similar incident where my system crashed (windows blue screen error) while I was on my working branch. I had tens of other WIP branches and didn't want to lose them. I found out that my HEAD was not resolving to a valid ref. Below are the steps I followed for the fix:

1. First point the HEAD to the master branch by running `echo ref: refs/heads/master>.git/HEAD` in the root directory of your repo. You will be checked out to **master** branch. Also, you may have your uncommitted local changes and your local working branch must be **missing**.
2. Check your uncommitted changes `git status`. Stash these changes using `git stash`.
3. Create your working branch again (which was lost due to corrupted git repo) by using `git checkout -b feature_abc`.
4. Bring back the uncommitted changes to their right place by running `git stash pop`.
5. You can now safely commit your changes in the working branch.

**Note:** If you had multiple un-pushed commits on your affected branch, you will lose them though the actual changes would still be there. You can just do separate commits again or go with a single commit marking the restoration of the branch after the corrupted repo incident.